# Postgres: Save rows from temp table before rollback

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, transactions, rollback

I have a main procedure (p_proc_a) in which I create a temp table for logging (tmp_log). In the main procedure I call some other procedures (p_proc_b, p_proc_c). In each of these procedures I insert data into table tmp_log.

How do I save rows from tmp_log into a physical table (log) in case of exception before rollback?

```
create procedure p_proc_a
language plpgsql
as $body$
begin

  create temp table tmp_log (log_message text) on commit drop;

  call p_proc_b();
  call p_proc_c();

  insert into log (log_message) 
  select log_message from tmp_log;

  exception
    when others then
      begin
        get stacked diagnostics
          v_message_text = message_text;

        insert into log (log_message)
        values(v_message_text);
      end;
end;
  $body$
```

What is a workround to save logs into a table and rollback changes from p_proc_b and p_proc_c?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible in PostgreSQL.

The typical workaround is to use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) to connect to the database itself and write the logs via dblink.

Comment: Thank you for tip. I make a workaround using json (inout) parameter for every procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I found three solutions to store data within a transaction (im my case - for debugging propose), and still be able to see that data after `rollback`-ing the transaction

I have a scenario where inside, I use following block, so it may not apply to your scenario

```
DO $$
BEGIN
...
ROLLBACK;
END;
$$;
```

Two first solutions are suggested to me in the Postgres slack, and the other I tried and found after talking with them, a way that worked in other db.

## Solutions

### 1 - Using DBLink

I don't remember how it was done, but you import some libraries and then connect to another db, and use the other DB - *which maybe can support to be this db* - which seem to be not affected by transactions

### 2 - Using COPY command

Using the

```
COPY (SELECT ...) TO PROGRAM 'psql -c "COPY xyz FROM stdin"'
```

BTW I never used it, and it seems that it requires `Super User`(`SU`) permission in Unix. And god knows how it is used, or how it output data

### 3 - Using Sub-Transactions

<s>In this way, you use a sub-transaction (which I'm not sure it it's correct, but it must be called *Autonomous transactions*) to commit the result you want to keep.
In my case the command looks like this:
I used a Temp Table, but it seems (I'm not sure) to work with an actual table as well</s>

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE
    IF NOT EXISTS myZone AS
        SELECT * from public."Zone"
        LIMIT 0;

DO $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public."Zone" (...)VALUES(...);

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myZone
        SELECT * from public."Zone";

    commit;
    END;

    Rollback;
END; $$;

SELECT * FROM myZone;

DROP TABLE myZone;
```

*don't ask what is the purpose of doing this, I'm creating a test scenario, and I wished to track what I did until now. since this block did not support `SELECT` of DQL, I had to do something else, and I wanted a clean set of report, not raising errors*

> According to [www.techtarget.com](https://www.techtarget.com/searchoracle/definition/autonomous-transaction):
>
> > ****Autonomous transactions** allow a single transaction to be subdivided into multiple commit/rollback transactions, each of which
> > will be tracked for auditing purposes. When an autonomous transaction
> > is called, the original transaction (calling transaction) is
> > temporarily suspended.*
>
> (This text was indexed by google and existed on 2022-10-11, and the website was not opened due to an E-mail validation issue)
>
> Also this name seems to be coming from Oracle, which [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm) can relate

### EIDTED:

**Removing solution 3 as it won't work**

POSTGRES 11 Claim to support `Autonomous Transactions` but it's not what we may expect...

For this functionality Postgres introduced the SAVEPOINT:

```
SAVEPOINT <name of savepoint>;

<... CODE ...>
            
<RELEASE|ROLLBACK> SAVEPOINT <name of savepoint>;
```

Now the issue is:

1. If you use nested BEGIN, the COMMIT Inside the nested code can COMMIT everything, and the ROLLBACK in the outside block will do none (Not rolling back anything that happened before COMMIT of inner
2. If you use SAVEPOINT, it is only used to rollbacks part of the code, and even if you COMMIT it, the ROLLBACK in the outside block will rollback the SAVEPOINT too

Comment: @chivracq thank you, I just knew that StackOverflow suggests we do not link to other resources and use the answer to write it even if it is a duplicate. I wasn't aware of new rules, or side conditions, how to add source? just link? or Quote provide an option too?

Comment: There is no "new rule". Your answer shouldn't consist primarily of a link and should stand on its own, but if you do use someone else's text or information in a question or answer, you absolutely need to attribute the source. This is same as it's been for years.

Comment: @chivracq I found this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing, thank you